# Image dimension, ByteBuffer size and format don't match. Please check if the ByteBuffer is in the declared format

Tags: flutter, image, dart, pose-detection

Trying to detect poses with Google ML Kit, but when it comes to detecting poses I get this error, in the last line:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Image dimension, ByteBuffer size and format don't match. Please check if the ByteBuffer is in the decalred format.

Pose detector:

```
final poseDetector = PoseDetector(
    options: PoseDetectorOptions(
      mode: PoseDetectionMode.single, 
      model: PoseDetectionModel.accurate,
    )
  );
```

Detect pose function:

```
void detePose(XFile file) async {
final myFile = File(file.path);
final Uint8List imageBytes = await myFile.readAsBytes();
final dimensions = await getImageDimensions(imageBytes);

int bytesperrow = dimensions['width'] * 4;
int width = dimensions['width'];
int height = dimensions['height'];
var format = dimensions['format'];

// print(format);

final inputImage = InputImage.fromBytes(
  bytes: imageBytes,
  metadata: InputImageMetadata(
    size: Size(
      width.toDouble(),
      height.toDouble()
    ),
    format: InputImageFormat.bgra8888,
    rotation: InputImageRotation.rotation0deg,
    bytesPerRow: bytesperrow
  )
);

final List<Pose> poses = await poseDetector.processImage(inputImage);
```

}

Comment: present the file's name and contents. justify your use of `readAsBytes` and `InputImage.fromBytes` on this data.